# Is there a website where people around the world can discuss research during writing?

Tags: research-process

Authors and readers can discuss about the writing of authors including ideas, experience design, hypothesis etc., like what people discuss at stackoverflow, rather than authors only get feedbacks until publishing the paper after all work done.

I am wondering if there is any website for researchers **around the world** to discuss about their research.  (Thanks for Buffy.)

I know researchgate but it seems not for the purpose.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome!  It's not super clear what you're asking.  Could you add a bit more detail about what you're looking for?

Comment: Updated. Thank you.

Comment: This sort of thing is normally done in research seminars. They can be local or distributed. But the people participating need to be both informed and interested. Many large universities have a number of such specialized seminars for faculty and advanced students.

Comment: I doubt that a general one would do anyone any good. It needs to be specialized to be valuable. This implies that there are several of them, but they are only known to the participants. You may need to create one around a circle of collaborators. These have gone on for more than fifty years, originally just by mailing (not emailing) papers in progress to colleagues around the world.

Comment: If it's a physics paper, or closely related to physics, you could try sending it to https://arxiv.org/. Not sure it's what you are looking for, but it's one way to let people look and get feedback without sending it to a journal. I don't know what's available like this for other than physics.

Comment: On what scientific domain? History is not the same as artificial intelligence or quantum chemistry !

Comment: I wish there is a place to discuss manuscripts decisions. Sometimes you wonder who is wrong (editor or yourself)

Comment: Jun, I concur with @BasileStarynkevitch that this question would be more answerable if you specify the discipline you're interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 20th century newsgroups like, e.g.,

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sci.physics

were perfect for this, they still exist and you can narrow down the scope and audience of such a group by creating one on your own. Nowadays probably more scientists in such a field post and read on bulletin boards like

https://www.physicsforums.com/

or

https://physics.stackexchange.com.

But, professional scientists don't have much time for long discussions. I think this is also the reason the Q&A format attracts much more then bulletin boards or formerly newsgroups. Academia is about asking the right questions, if you have the question, you have to work on it based on scientific rigor and methodology. There is not so much to discuss publicly before or during doing this work or writing papers and hypothesis. Science is about coming up with a way to solve or answer a question and comparing/commenting on that. The aftermath, discussions come *afterwards*, when work and answers have been published. So my experience is with disccusion formats you attract in best case undergraduates and early PhD students still learning. Professional scientists mostly have private or public discussions on conferences.

So the best option you might have to discuss with experts on your topics online are virtual conferences where maybe a chat or comment app is attached to each talk. I'm wondering myself how easy and cheap web-technology has become here as I'm now registered for a big conference in my field which will not be canceled with respect to corona virus due to organization cost but many presentations will be shown online after remote registration.

Researchgate I think also can work for this if you have enough followers reading your posted questions. Online, the question is always how do you advertise your post to readers and commenters you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

There may be no *exact* answer to your question, but below I list a couple of sites that purport to do what you are referring to:

- **Paperhive**: Paperhive is a co-working hub for researchers and allows one to upload your article and open it up for other researchers to discuss. You may need to upload your article to arXiv or a similar preprint archive to use PaperHive. It definitely seems (from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvGG_KOCcJc) that the articles are open to the scientific community to discuss.
- **Morressier**: It seems as though Morressier allows you to upload conference posters and shorter-form findings and reveal it to the global community. I do not know it they allow you to discuss the work.
- **Figshare**: Figshare is a site that allows you to upload shorter form research findings and share it with the research community. I do not know if they allow you to discuss your results.
- **Pubpeer**: Is an online journal club that is really popular in the biological sciences. It seems that you can discuss any published research as well as preprints. It is, therefore, possible to get feedback prior to publishing with a large publisher.
- **Orvium**: Orvium is a startup that aims to radically change the way peer review is done. It seems as though their platform can be used to upload your research and get reviews outside of the traditional publishing cycle.
- **Researchgate**: As you have mentioned, Researchgate has a question board where you can ask anything. It is, therefore, a platform where researchers may discuss their research. Apart from the questions board, I now see that you can formally request feedback on an article from anyone. It, therefore, seems to be an ideal place to get feedback if you can convince people to spend time on your article.

I also suggest listening to Episode 76 of Everything Hertz (https://everythinghertz.com/). I recall them discussing Open review.

Answer (score 2):

> Authors and readers can discuss about the writing of authors including ideas, experience design, hypothesis etc.,

### Consider also participating to face to face meetings and research seminars.

#### (Since you are located near Paris, France and seems interested in PHP)

If you are near Paris and interested in information technology, [INRIA](https://www.inria.fr/), [ENS Ulm](https://www.ens.fr), [LIP6](https://www.lip6.fr), [Collège de France](https://www.college-de-france.fr/), [CNRS](http://www.cnrs.fr/), [CEA LIST](http://www-list.cea.fr/)  have many research seminars that you can attend freely, and ask questions about your ideas. Also [AFIA](https://afia.asso.fr/). I gave there a [talk](http://refpersys.org/Starynkevitch-CAIA-RefPerSys-2020mar06.pdf) yesterday related to http://refpersys.org/ at a [seminar in honor of the late Jacques Pitrat](https://afia.asso.fr/journee-hommage-j-pitrat/).

On a more industrial mode near Paris, consider attending [Systematic](https://systematic-paris-region.org) or [CapDigital](https://www.capdigital.com/) or [Syntec](https://syntec-numerique.fr/) meetings.

Or many [meetups](https://www.meetup.com/).

Most French universities and [Grandes Écoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandes_%C3%A9coles) (e.g. [Telecom Paris](https://www.telecom-paris.fr/) but also [EPITA](https://www.epita.fr/) or [Centrale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrale_Graduate_School)) organize regular research seminars that anyone can attend. You may need to subscribe to mailing lists or perhaps pay a small fee (a few dozens of euros) to attend them.

Use google to find seminar close to your research interests.

The [LIP6 computer science](http://documentation.sorbonne-universites.fr/bibliotheques/sciences-ingenierie/bibliotheque-mir-mathematiques-informatique-recherche.html) university research library is helpful too. You'll find names of computer scientists easily there.

> I am wondering if there is any 'online' seminar site for researchers around the world? Researchers can discuss about their research.

### You should consider meeting researchers face to face.

In the Paris region there are many of them in information technology (including at [CEA LIST](http://www-list.cea.fr) where I work, or [Université Paris Saclay](https://www.universite-paris-saclay.fr/), [ENS Paris Saclay](https://ens-paris-saclay.fr/en), [Ecole Polytechnique](https://www.polytechnique.edu/), ....). Since face to face communication is giving more bandwidth (non-verbal communication) than most electronic media. See also [séminaire codes sources](https://codesource.hypotheses.org/).

Notice that Google and Facebook have research labs in Paris and they also sometimes organize seminars.

In 2020, research ideas related to software are practically using [open source](https://opensource.org/) or [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) proof-of-concept prototypes (read about [TRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_readiness_level) and attend [Horizon2020](https://www.horizon2020.gouv.fr/) or [HorizonEurope](https://ec.europa.eu/info/horizon-europe-next-research-and-innovation-framework-programme_en) meetings; you might meet me there). Perhaps organizations like [APRIL](https://www.april.org/) or [AFUL](https://aful.org/) or [IRILL](https://www.irill.org/) might be a good way to meet persons.

### computer science research site

Obviously [cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) comes to mind

### practical advice

If you are excessively scared to meet people in person (and I am also very shy), consider using the help of [some psychotherapist](https://www.psychologue.net/). My wife happens to be one.

PS. You could also send me an email (in English or French) to `basile@starynkevitch.net` mentioning the URL of your question, your actual research interests in computer science, etc...